# responsive jQuery functions depending @media

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple js to change style when map area is hover. But in iPad (like other tablets, i guess) hover does not show - just mouseup event.

I already have this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscocarvalho/7v8y5/5/), I almost know that in screen I need mouseeneter and in Touch screens I need mouseup (same thing as mouseleave and mouseout), the question is: how I develop this for this 2 options?

js here:

```
$.noConflict();
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('.map_hovered').maphilight();
        jQuery('.wind').mouseenter(function () {
            jQuery('.wind_changer_hover').addClass('fancy');
        });

        jQuery('.wind').mouseleave(function () {
            jQuery('.wind_changer_hover').removeClass('fancy');
        });
    });

    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('.map_pressed').maphilight();
        jQuery('.wind').mouseup(function () {
            jQuery('.wind_changer_press').addClass('fancy');
        });

        jQuery('.wind').mouseout(function () {
            jQuery('.wind_changer_press').removeClass('fancy');
        });
    });
```

Comment: have a look at Enquire.js -> http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

Comment: @patrick it looks great, thanks! But now pop up other relevant point: I can't ask if there are a TouchScreen only using @media query, media query allows me to catch the resolution of screen.
In fact I fount this:
`<script type="text/javascript">
    var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
    if(is_touch_device) alert("touch is enabled!");
</script>`
But now I need the js to normal version (not touch screen).

Comment: You can use Modernizr ( http://modernizr.com/ ) so you can do if (Modernizr.touch) {}. But I think it's better have an alternate solution. You can have pc (windows 8 mainly) with both mouse and touch support so you should disable mouse events there.